# Adding the row and columns as frame ticks

Tags: image-processing

This code:

```
i = Import["ExampleData/ocelot.jpg"];
Show[i, Frame -> True]
```

Gives this image.

[image]

However, the margins have indices measured from the lower left corner, distinguished as the point (0,0).

Anyone have a simple way to have these tick labels measure from the upper left corner, distinguishing the rows and columns instead of the x and y indices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More general solution, since you can put any label. Although more code than `ArrayPlot`

```
i = Import["ExampleData/ocelot.jpg"];
    Show[i, Frame -> True, 
     FrameTicks -> {Range[0, 200, 50], 
       Transpose@{Range[0, 200, 50], Range[200, 0, -50]}}]
```

[image]

You can control where to put the ticks

```
i = Import["ExampleData/ocelot.jpg"];
xTicks = Range[0, 200, 50];
yTicks = Transpose@{Range[0, 200, 50], Range[200, 0, -50]};
Show[i, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {None, yTicks, xTicks, None}]
```

[image]

Comment: What I see in the documentation is FrameTicks->{{left,right},{bottom,top}} but apparently FrameTicks->{{0,50,100},{100,150,200}} puts them bottom, top, then left,right? Am I correct? I just can't find any examples of this in the documentation.

Comment: @David I edited the answer...

Comment: Very nice edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
ArrayPlot[1 - ImageData[i], Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Starts counting at `1`, of course-

Comment: `1- ImageData[i]` is really nice!